# Show that $\oplus\widetilde{M}_{\alpha}\cong \widetilde{\oplus M_{\alpha}}$ with $M_{\alpha}$ $\mathcal{O}_{X}(X)$-modules.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ be an affine scheme, and let $M_{\alpha}$-be $A$-modules. I want to show that $\oplus\widetilde{M}_{\alpha}\cong\widetilde{\oplus M_{\alpha}}$.

Let $D(f)$ be a distinguished open in $X$, then notice by construction we have
$$\widetilde{\oplus M_{\alpha}}(D(f)) = (\oplus M_{\alpha})_{f} \cong \oplus M_{\alpha,f} = \oplus\widetilde{M_{\alpha}}(D(f)).$$

Are we then able to conclude that since the two sheaves on $X$ agree on the distinguished opens (which form a basis), that we actually have $\oplus\widetilde{M}_{\alpha}\cong\widetilde{\oplus M_{\alpha}}$?

Comment: $\widetilde{.}$ is left adjoint to the global sections functor. See Hartshorne exercise II.5.3. Then use that left adjoints preserve coproducts.

Comment: @DavidLui this looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it below?

Comment: @KReiser It's not really a full answer, since you have to solve exercise II.5.3 first.

Comment: @DavidLui I do not think this is such a big deal - leaving adjointness as an exercise to the reader after explaining what it is or [citing a solution](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01I7) are both reasonable ways to make it in to a full answer.

Comment: @DavidLui Thanks for your help. This is indeed a nice solution. Is it also possible to reason in the way as I did, by giving isomorphisms on the distinguished opens? Or are there any additional things we have to show before this induces an isomorphism of the sheaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\widetilde{-}$ is left adjoint to the global sections functor. See Hartshorne exercise II.5.3. Then use that left adjoints preserve coproducts.

For the isomorphism on distinguished open sets, you need to find a morphism of sheaves that induces those isomorphisms on distinguished open sets.